# BluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery() doesn't discovers those bluetooth devices(Smart Phones in my case) whose screen is off

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have been trying to discover all neighbouring bluetooth devices(Classic Bluetooth in my case) using the startDiscovery() function of the bluetoothAdapter. But the problem is, only those devices are discovered whose bluetooth screen in settings is opened, or in other words all smartphones whose screen is turned off aren't discovered. I would like to discover every neighbouring device whose bluetooth is turned on. Following are the code snippets I have been using for doing the above job:

```
//Broadcast Receiver for getting bluetooth devices
    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                System.out.println("A device was found!"+bluetoothDevice.getName());
            }
        }
    };

//Registering the broadcast receiver
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);

    }

//Calling the startDiscovery() function of the bluetoothAdapter
    public void discoverDevices(View v){
        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        System.out.println("Bluetooth Discovery has started");
    }
```

I have searched a lot of places for getting this but was unsuccessful, any leads into the same would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Android developers API reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#startDiscovery()) clearly states the following:

> Device discovery will only find remote devices that are currently discoverable (inquiry scan enabled). Many Bluetooth devices are not discoverable by default, and need to be entered into a special mode.

You might have to come to terms with the idea that what you are trying to do is not going to work.